# How to convert static plot to animation (poliastro)?

Tags: python, animation, orbital-mechanics

I have plotted an orbit, but I need it as an animation, not a static plot

```
import poliastro
from poliastro.bodies import Earth
from poliastro.twobody import Orbit

r = [-8045, -3490, 2500] * u.km
v = [-3.457, 6.618, 2.533] * u.km / u.s

orb = Orbit.from_vectors(Earth, r, v)
# orb.plot()
# poliastro.plotting.OrbitPlotter3D(orb)
p = OrbitPlotter3D()
p.plot(orb,color='red')
```